# Replace function is not working for the body section using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to replace contents on my webpage as some of my words are having spaces between them, which we can view when we view source code but that spaces should be replaced on the web page on the front end.

Below is the code which i am using

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/Auto matic/g, 'Automatic'));
```

But it`s not working, my page gets hang and shows error as

"Oxygen occurs an error"

As i m using CMS i m not able to do the require. Please help out me.

Comment: Works for me see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/VwHcL/)

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this. You are re-drawing the entire document. Any event listeners would be lost, images would potentially be re-downloaded etc.. Alternatively you should target the exact elements which need replacing.

Comment: So can you suggest me the code for the above requirement???

Comment: +100 to most of what Curt said - `.html` can be used to access the contents of an element, or sometimes for creating elements, but it should _never_ be used to seralise an element and then reserialise it again.

Comment: @Coder it's a non-trivial problem - you would have to recursively traverse the entire DOM tree looking for "text nodes" and then perform the replacement on those.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against doing this. You are re-drawing the entire document. Any event listeners would be lost, images would potentially be re-downloaded etc.. Alternatively you should target the exact elements which need replacing.

For example:

```
$(".description").text(function(i,v) {
  return v.replace(/Auto matic/g, 'Automatic');
});
```

If you have these issues all over the site, then you have a global content issue which should be resolved at the source.

Comment: `.text` will pass the existing text to the function as the second parameter - no need to call `$(this).text()` internally

Comment: Thnks Curt. But even this is also not working. Its removing my whole script while loading the page on CMS. I m not able to edit my CMS page... :(

Comment: I tried for div element as  

$("body").html($("#desc").html().replace(/Auto matic/g, 'Automatic'));


But then its not working....